# Apache Camel 2.13.1 MyBatis Transaction not rolled back

Tags: apache-camel, mybatis

I have a scenario, where I have to first update a row in three  tables, then insert a new row into each of those tables. All this should be in a single batch of statements and rollback if it fails.

```
Scenario below
e.g
statement1 = update table1;
statement2= update table2;
statement3 =update table3;
statement4 insert into table1;
statement5 insert into table2;
statement6 insert into tables3
```

**The answer to the above question by the Camel Community was to use a Transactional Client, but now the issue is with the transaction not being rolled back on failure of one of the MyBatis statements.**

```
E.g. Exception case:The first two updates were not rolled back on failure of the third one below:

.to("mybatis:userMapper.updatePerson?statementType=Update") --- Passed
.to("mybatis:userMapper.updateCertificate8?statementType=Update") ---- Passed
.to("mybatis:userMapper.updateApplicationGroup?statementType=Update") ---- Failed

**`Am I missing anything?`**

    Camel Registry
            SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
            DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(
            sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().getEnvironment()
                                                            .getDataSource());
                            registry.put("transactionManager",dataSourceTransactionManager);
                            SpringTransactionPolicy springTransactionPolicy = new SpringTransactionPolicy();
                            springTransactionPolicy.setTransactionManager(dataSourceTransactionManager);
                            springTransactionPolicy.setPropagationBehaviorName("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED");
                            registry.put("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED",springTransactionPolicy);
                            camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
                            camelContext.setTracing(true);
                            camelContext.start();


    Camel Route:
                    onException(JMSException.class)
                    .handled(true).maximumRedeliveries(0).end();

                    onException(IllegalArgumentException.class)
                    .handled(true).maximumRedeliveries(0).rollback("Rolling back the IllegalArgumentException")
                    .end();

                    onException(PersistenceException.class)
                    .handled(true).maximumRedeliveries(0).rollback("Rolling back the transaction")
                    .end();

                    onException(RollbackExchangeException.class)
                    .handled(false).maximumRedeliveries(0).process(new CamelTibcoMessageProcessor())
                    .end();

 from("timer:foo?period=10000")
 .policy("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED")                                 .to("mybatis:userMapper.updatePerson?statementType=Update")
                                    .to("mybatis:userMapper.updateCertificate8?statementType=Update")
                                    .to("mybatis:userMapper.updateApplicationGroup?statementType=Update")
                                    .to("mybatis:userMapper.insertPersonFromCAMSCTSBridge?statementType=InsertList&executorType=batch")
                    .end();
```

Comment: try using .transacted("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED") instead of policy(). I've never seen policy() used for transacting a route.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the solution is straightforward  see link for [Camel MyBatis](http://camel.apache.org/mybatis.html) and [MyBatis-Spring](https://mybatis.github.io/spring/factorybean.html)  .

Convert the Spring config to Java and you have it. Below is what I did and it worked fine.

Add **mybatis-spring** maven dependency to your pom.

```
**------------------Sample setup--------------------**

SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc_url");
cpds.setUser("username");
cpds.setPassword("password");

TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy transactionAwareDataSourceProxy = new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(cpds);
DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(transactionAwareDataSourceProxy);
registry.put("transactionManager",transactionManager);
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
SqlSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
                        factoryBean.setConfigLocation(appContext.getResource("mapper/your_mybatis_config.xml"));
factoryBean.setDataSource(cpds);

SpringTransactionPolicy  propagationRequired = new SpringTransactionPolicy();
propagationRequired.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
propagationRequired.setPropagationBehaviorName("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED");
registry.put("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED",propagationRequired);

SpringTransactionPolicy  propagationRequiredNew= new SpringTransactionPolicy();
propagationRequiredNew.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
propagationRequiredNew.setPropagationBehaviorName("PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW");
registry.put("PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW",propagationRequiredNew);

 camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
camelContext.setTracing(true);
camelContext.start();

 MyBatisComponent component = new MyBatisComponent();
component.setSqlSessionFactory(factoryBean.getObject());
camelContext.addComponent("mybatis", component);
 camelContext.addRoutes(new SomeRoute());
```